# TypeError: User.findById is not a function

Tags: javascript, backend

I tell you my problem. I'm with my first server; Log in fine but when trying to pass the view to index.pug I get this error.
**TypeError: User.findById is not a function**

I have reviewed the code thoroughly, I found some fault and I have solved it, ... I think. The program starts session and it returns me JSON when it has registered and authenticated in the bbdd.

This is my middleware **middlewares/find_user.js**

```
const User = require('../models').User;//Modelo User

module.exports = function(req,res,next){

  if(!req.session.userId) return next(); //Sí userId no existe next.

  User.findById(req.session.userId).then(user=>{
      if(user){//Sí user existe,
       req.user = user;//meter valor de user en req.user, para que lo usen otros middleware.
       next();//next al siguiente middleware.
    }
  })
};
```

This is my **sessions.js** controllers

```
const User = require('../models').User;//importamos el modelo user.js

module.exports = {
  new: function(req,res){//despliega el formulario de autenticacion
    res.render('sessions/new');//renderiza la vista sessions/new.pug.
  },//en lin 5:new debe coincidir el nombre con la vista y la acccion.
  create: function(req,res){//recibe los datos del formulario para crear-
                            // la sesion y hacer el Login.
    User.login(req.body.email, req.body.password)
    .then(user => {
      if(user){//si hay usuario guardamos la sesion.
        req.session.userId = user.id;//guardar el id del user en una sesion user.Id
                                     //de la sesion UserId
      }
      res.json(user);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err);
        res.json(err);
      })
  }
};
```

This is my **registrations.js** controller

```
  new: function(req,res){
    res.render('registrations/new');
  },
  create: function(req,res){
    let data = {
      email: req.body.email,
      password: req.body.password
    };

    User.create(data).then(result=>{
      res.json(result);
    }).catch(err=>{
      res.json(err);
    });
  }
};
```

Only just in case;
My **registrations_routes.js**:

```
const express = require('express');//importamos express.

let RegistrationsController = require('../controllers/registrations.js');
let router = express.Router();//metemos en el objeto router el metodo Router de express.


router.get('/signup',RegistrationsController.new);//ruta crear un nuevo registro/usuario.

router.route('/users').post(RegistrationsController.create);

module.exports = router;
```

and my **sessions_routes.js**:

```
const express = require('express');//importamos express

let SessionsController = require('../controllers/sessions');//importa el-
                                                  // controlador de sessions.js

var router = express.Router();//metemos en el objeto JSON router, el metodo-
                              // Router de express.

router.route('/sessions')
.get(SessionsController.new)//peticion GET.
.post(SessionsController.create);//peticion POST.

module.exports = router;//exportamos router para poder montarlo en la aplicacion.
```

My intention is to be able to redirect to the "/" view and that the mail of the person who has logged in appears, when I implement it I get that error.
Thank you so much for everything.

**This is my error file**

```
at module.exports (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\middlewares\find_user.js:7:8)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (F:\Documentos Andres\Programacion\BackEnd\Proyecto3\base_datos\node_modules\express-session\index.js:489:7)
    at runCallback (timers.js:706:11)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
```

My model **user.js**:

```
'use strict';

const bcrypt =require('bcrypt');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {//Modelo de tabla users.
      email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,//validacion, solo un igual en bbdd
      allowNull: false//no permite que se quede vacio
    },
    password_hash: DataTypes.STRING,//Pass encriptado a string.
    password: DataTypes.VIRTUAL//pass sin encriptar a memoria virtual.
  }, {});

  User.login = function(email,password){//funcion login de User que busca un registro y lo almacena en login
    return User.findOne({//busca uno en concreto.
      where: {
        email: email//En campo email bucar el email dado. O "email" por shorthand propertys.
      }
    }).then(user=>{
      if(!user) return null;//si no existe el usuario en bbdd devuelve nulo.
      return user.authenticatePassword(password).then(valid=> valid ? user : null);//o tambien ".then(valid=> valid ? user : null);"
      });
  };

  User.prototype.authenticatePassword = function(password){//compara el pass dado y el hash de la bbdd.
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{//devuelve promesa.
      bcrypt.compare(password,this.password_hash,function(err,valid){//compara , si ok valid, sí nok err.
        if(err){return rej(err);} //no coincide hash de bbdd con pass dado =>err

        res(valid);//sí coincide hash de bbd con pass dado =>valid.
      })
    })
  };

  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };

  User.beforeCreate(function(user,options){//Antes de guardar encriptar.
    return new Promise((res,rej)=>{//retorna una promesa

      if(user.password){//si se introduce un pass.
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function(error,hash){//algoritmo de encriptacion
         user.password_hash = hash;//se guarda el pass encriptado.
         res();//con esto decimos que ha ido bien, Para continuar
       })
     };
    });
  });
  return User;
};
```

Comment: You put lot of code but the most important is missing, can you show how your `models.js` look like?  the one that have `findById` function?

Comment: `findById` don't return promise instead try with callback. See here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Comment: jcubic; Sorry for putting so much code, but I do not know where the fault is. I find the findById function in the find_user middleware. But I added another user.js model file Is this what you want? and thank you very much for your attention

Comment: Vikash Singh,Thank you for answering, I am looking at what you have sent me but I do not see where I can correct it. If you could tell me a little more concrete, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [findByPk](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findByPk), rather than findById (I cannot find findById in the sequelize docs).

Comment: Bravo friend that was it. I do not want to abuse you, but if it is not in the sequelize docs, is it deprecated ??
Once again, thank you very much, you have taken me out of the black hole. And also thank you very much to the 2 other colleagues who have helped. I clear the question or leave it?

Comment: Not sure if findById was deprecated - usually, a deprecated method would work (and you would get a warning message).  But, it's gone now.